# The non-singular term in the transformation of the free energy per lattice site (Or: Is Cardy wrong about the RG transformation)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, renormalization

In *Scaling and renormalization in statistical physics* by *Cardy* on page 44 he asserts that the free energy per lattice site defined by $f(\{K\})\equiv-N^{-1} \ln Z$ transforms as

$$f(\{K\})=g(\{K\})+b^{-d} f(\{K'\}) \tag{1}$$
under a renormalization group transformation.

Here the first term is non-singular and the second singular term determines the critical exponents etc. I want to understand where the first non-singular term comes from.

Note that under the renormalization group the partition function is preserved, i.e.

$$Z(\{K\})=\mathrm{tr}_{\mathrm{conf}} e^{-H(\{K\})}=\mathrm{tr}_{\mathrm{conf'}} e^{-H'(\{K'\})}=Z(\{K'\}) . \tag{2}$$
Here the change in the couplings is exactly undone by the change in the configuration space that is summed over.

So clearly $\ln Z$ is preserved and any change in $f(\{K\})$ can only come from a change in $N$. This change explains how the second term arises but I don't understand how we could possibly get the first non-singular term.

(Perhaps I misunderstood the notation and $f(\{K'\})$ is meant to mean something like
$-N^{-1} \ln \mathrm{tr}_{\mathrm{conf}} e^{-H({K'})} $ with only the couplings replaced, but that would make a lot less sense in the rest of the chapter.)

Comment: Does Cardy give an explicit example of the Hamiltonians H(K) and H'(K') when making this statement? I suspect the issue is that constant terms have been omitted from the Hamiltonians. While these constants cancel out of the probabilities e^{-H}/Z, if they are neglected in the Hamiltonian they show up in Z to compensate. Since constants are in general generated by coarse-graining, omitting them from the coarse-grained Hamiltonian there will cause a discrepancy between the free energy calculated from H' and that calculated from H.

Comment: @bbrink, ah you mean that equation (2) is not exact. That would explain it. It does not seem to be the case though. In the explicit example it is $H'(\{K'\})$ that changes to $N' g(K) - K' \sum_i s_i s_{i+1}$ (so it contains something looking like the constant extra factor). But it is explicitly stated and used that Z itself is preserved.

(See eq 3.10 of Cardy)

Comment: (We find that this has to be the new Hamiltonian by the very fact that Z is preserved. It does seem like things could work out if instead we imposed something like $Z \to Z \exp{N' g(K)}$ but that is clearly not what Cardy does. Nor would I know where this transformation would come from.

Comment: No, Eq. 2 is exact: the partition function is preserved by the coarse graining operation. What I mean is that if you have a Hamiltonian e.g., for the Ising model, $H(\{K\}) = h \sum_i s_i + J\sum_{ij} s_i s_j$, you will often see the coarse-grained & rescaled Hamiltonian given as  $H(\{K'\}) = h' \sum_i s'_i + J' \sum_{ij} s'_i s'_j$. However, this is not quite right, as coarse graining will generate a constant term $K'_0$ that has been neglected here. If you use this $H(\{K'\})$ that neglects $K'_0$ to calculate Z' it will differ from the Z you calculate from $H(\{K\})$ by $e^{K'_0}$

Comment: This could be one possible source of the constant offset in the free energy, but I am not sure if Cardy neglects this constant so I did not want to offer it as a definite answer.

Comment: @bbrink, yes that sounds likely. But an equivalent way of saying this is that the constant term comes from the fact that what Cardy calls Z' is not the full new Z as found under the renormalization group, i.e. not  Z{H} = Z'{H'}.

Instead he defines a new $H'' = H' - \mathrm{cst terms]$ and a new Z'' that where the exponential contains only this H'', with the overall constant taken out of Z''. So $Z''{H''} \neq Z{H}$. This seems to be really bad notation that he is using.